# AJAX JQUERY PHP - Creating a viewpane for information

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I've been really stumped on this issue for the past week and after countless hours of it not working, I am hoping someone more knowledgeable may be able to help! :)

I am creating a view pane which has a list of divs done one side holding a small bit of information such as a title and then once these have been clicked on more detailed information shows on the left. To do this have it linked up to a database which stores information ( for this it is record information).

The image attached shows an outline of what I am aiming for. There is also a screen grab of my database uploaded.

I have created the basic outline of it (albeit a rather ugly one for now! ) but I cannot get the information to show on the left hand side when it is clicked on.

The only error I have on the console is : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < 
On the connect_and_get page. I have already run the code through visual studio but didn't find any errors.

I would **really** appreciate any help.
Please see the code attached: https://bitbucket.org/snippets/AimeeH/je56K

Many many thanks in advance

[Layout I'm aiming for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KoGW.png)

Comment: Post your code in your question, not as an image.

Comment: If the username and password for your database connection in your code are real, you should delete them ASAP.

Comment: Thanks Luke ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who might want to reference this, I did get it working in the end although I am not completely sure as to why ( I am still very new at this!) here's what I remember doing, I really hope it helps!!

1. I changed all the " marks into ' (turned all the quotes into singular ones) as I read that PHP can sometimes have issues with this.
2. I actually uploaded the code to an online server (I used C-Panel) instead of running it on my computer with a local server running. This also meant that I made a new database for c-panel as the data would now all be accessed through this.
3. I added the user name in front of the table name (as this was how cpanel recognised the table name)

These were the main changes I made, and then using the console on Google chrome I worked through all the errors that popped up. As now the error messages being given were clear and useful.

I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a syntax error

```
<?php

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

`<script>` is not valid php. Either exit the PHP (`?>`) or echo the line.